# PHP validate form having different fields displayed on javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have trouble validating a form that changes its fields based on javascript. The idea is that the form displays different fields added dynamically based on a radio button choice. However PHP appears to get confused based on the logic I made. Say I check for the fields that are actually set. I tried writing an if, else logic checking if $_POST variables were set with isset, but it didn't work. Now the code I have does a check for the whole form being submitted (checking the name of the submit button), and then, inside that check, I check for all the other fields, like so:

```
else if(isset($_POST['subirLic']) && isset($_POST['BusquedaTerm'])){ 
//the first variable is the name of the submit button and the second is a hidden field, then inside the block I check for the existence of the fields for example: if(isset($_POST['whatever'])) {}
```

The problem is that I want to check that the first set of fields is submitted, and also check if the other fields (those that display based on a javascript function) are not submitted.

I tried to build a decision logic but I am all messed up, currently I do the check like I described above, then I check if the variables are set that must go into the database query, but the page behaves very oddly. For example I fill the additional fields, and then PHP tries to do a query that I built for the other set of fields.

I am trying to handle the decision based on a code like this:

```
    if(isset($EgresoLicen)&&isset($IngresoLicen)&&isset($CedLic)&&isset($FacultLic)&&isset($GenerLic)&&isset($cuentaDep)&&isset($TesisLicen)) {//here do the query to the database}
```

and the other decision that the code should make goes like this:

```
if(isset($EgresoLicen)&&isset($ingresoLicen)&&isset($FacultLic)&&isset($GenerLic)&&isset($cuentaDep)&&isset($AsesorLic)&&isset($TitProyecto)&&isset($Modalidad)) {//same thing }
```

But as I said, PHP gets confused apparently because the two if choices contain almost identical variables.

OK guys, I'll paste the code because I keep looking at it and can only think it is correct, although it evidently isn't. It is only part of the whole code at the page, that has about five more forms (it is an administrative panel to add info to a database). The other forms work fine, but they don't get any additional fields added, so I can simply check if all the $_POST variables in them are set, and validate each one by one, the problem with the one I mentioned is in my opinion that the $_POST variables are repeatedly checked and this gets confused the whole task, but I can't think of any other way to do it, that is why I appreciate your suggestions (at this point I don't even know if the if statements are nested correctly, I remember working overnight and doing as many changes as I could). The code that handles the form in question is:

```
else if(isset($_POST['subirLic']) && isset($_POST['BusquedaTerm'])){
// the above statement starts with an else if because it is part of a larger set of       forms being checked---------------------
require_once('libreria.php');
if(isset($_POST['titulo'])) $Titulado = $_POST['titulo'];
if (isset($_POST['EgresoLic'])) {$EgresoLicenciado = $_POST['EgresoLic'];
$EgresoLicencia = new Zend_Validate_Date;
if ($EgresoLicencia->isValid($EgresoLicenciado)) $EgresoLicen = $EgresoLicenciado; else     $errorsLic['fechaEgreso']="Escriba la fecha de egreso de licenciatura, formato AAAA-MM-DD (sólo números separados por guiones)"; }
if (isset($_POST['IngresoLic'])) {$IngresoLicenciado= $_POST['IngresoLic'];
$IngresoLicencia = new Zend_Validate_Date;
if ($IngresoLicencia->isValid($IngresoLicenciado)) $IngresoLicen = $IngresoLicenciado;     else $errorsLic['fechaIngreso']="Escriba la fecha de ingreso a licenciatura, formato AAAA-  MM-DD (sólo números separados por guiones"; } 
if (isset($_POST['titulo']))$Titulado = $_POST['titulo'];
if(isset($_POST['genLic'])) {$GenerLicenciado =$_POST['genLic'];
if($GenerLicenciado !="" && preg_match('/^\d{4}/', $GenerLicenciado)==true) $GenerLic=  $GenerLicenciado;
else  $errorsLic['generacion'] = "Escriba el año de su generación en formato AAAA"; }
$cuentaDep= $_POST['cuentaLic']; //Escribir validación de cuenta ---------------->    pendiente
if(isset($_POST['facLic'])) {$FacultadLic= $_POST['facLic']; 
if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b) {6,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==5)) $FacultLic =  $FacultadLic; 
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b) {5,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==4)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==3)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==2)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==1)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){1,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==0)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else $errorsLic['facultad']= "Escriba la facultad en que estudió la licenciatura"; }
if(isset($_POST['titulo'])) $Titulado = $_POST['titulo'];
if(isset($_POST['CedProfLic'])) {$CedulaLic = $_POST['CedProfLic']; if($CedulaLic !="" && preg_match('/\d{2,9}/', $CedulaLic)==true) $CedLic=$CedulaLic; else      $errorsLic['cedula']="Escriba el número de su cédula profesional";} 
if(isset($_POST['TesisLic'])) {$TesisLicenciado = $_POST['TesisLic']; 
if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){11,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==10)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){10,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==9)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){9,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==8))     $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){8,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==7))  $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){7,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==6)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){6,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==5)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==4)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==3)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==2)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==1))  $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else $errorsLic['tesis']="Escriba el título de su tesis de licenciatura"; 
}

include_once ('conect_gral.php');//importante incluir este archivo en todas las  consultas, y sustituirlo por uno seguro con contraseña;
$registrobuscado=$_POST['BusquedaTerm'];
    if(isset($EgresoLicen)&&isset($IngresoLicen)&&isset($CedLic)&&isset($FacultLic)&&isset($GenerLic)&&isset($cuentaDep)&&isset($TesisLicen)) {
$cons4="SELECT CompletoApellidos FROM seguimientoegresados WHERE CompletoApellidos='registrobuscado'";
$regisLic = "UPDATE datos_licenciatura SET Fecha_Egreso_Lic='$EgresoLicen',   Fecha_Ingreso_Lic='$IngresoLicen', Ced_Profesional_Lic='$CedLic', Facultad_Lic='$FacultLic', Generacion_Lic='$GenerLic', Cuenta_Dependencia='$cuentaDep', Tesis_Lic='$TesisLicen' WHERE Apellido_Licen='$registrobuscado'";
$regisGrad= "UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Licenciado' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
if($Titulado=='pasante') $regisGrad="UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Pasante' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
$consultacuatro=mysql_query($cons4);
$registroLic = mysql_query($regisLic);
$registroGrado = mysql_query($regisGrad);
if (!$registroLic || !$registroGrado) echo "Ocurrió un error al registrar los datos en   la Base de Datos Registro Basico"; 
if (!$consultacuatro) {echo "No se ha podido localizar al usuario";}
} else echo "No se han registrado todos los datos";
//captura de datos de pasantes-->
//PRIMERA PARTE DEL FORMULARIO REVISAR
if(isset($_POST['asesor_proy'])) {$AsesorLicenciado = $_POST['asesor_proy'];
if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0- 9]+\D\b){5,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==4))    $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==3)) $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==2)) $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==1)) $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else $errorsLic['asesor_pas']="Escriba el nombre del asesor de su proyecto de pasante";}
if(isset($_POST['modalidad'])) $Modalidad =$_POST['modalidad'];
if(isset($_POST['proyecto'])){$TituloProyecto= $_POST['proyecto']; 
if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){10,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==9)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){9,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==8)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){8,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==7)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){7,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==6)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){6,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==5)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==4)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==3)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==2)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==1)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){1,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==0)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else $errorsLic['proyecto']="Escriba el título de su proyecto de pasante";
}      if(isset($EgresoLicen)&&isset($ingresoLicen)&&isset($CedLic)&&isset($FacultLic)&&isset($GenerLic)&&isset($cuentaDep)&&isset($AsesorLic)&&isset($TitProyecto)&&isset($Modalidad)) {
include_once ('conect_gral.php');//importante incluir este archivo en todas las consultas, y sustituirlo por uno seguro con contraseña;
$registrobuscado=$_POST['BusquedaTerm'];
$cons11="SELECT CompletoApellidos FROM seguimientoegresados WHERE CompletoApellidos='registrobuscado'";
$regisPas="UPDATE datos_licenciatura SET Fecha_Egreso_Lic='$EgresoLicen', Fecha_Ingreso_Lic='$IngresoLicen', Facultad_Lic='$FacultLic', Generacion_Lic='$GenerLic', Cuenta_Dependencia='$cuentaDep', Asesor_Pas='$AsesorLic', Proyecto_Pas='$TitProyecto', Modalidad_Pas='$Modalidad' WHERE Apellido_Licen='$registrobuscado'"; 
$regisGrad= "UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Licenciado' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
if($Titulado=='pasante') $regisGrad="UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Pasante' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
$consultaonce=mysql_query($cons11);
$registroPas = mysql_query($regisPas);
$registroGrado = mysql_query($regisGrad);
if (!$registroPas || !$registroGrado) echo "Ocurrió un error al registrar los datos en la Base de Datos";   
if (!$consultaonce) {echo "No se ha podido localizar al usuario";}
}
}
```

I know this is very large, I could have left out the whole validation statements but maybe there's an error that I can't find, perhaps you would recommend using a Zend_Validation instead, specially because I'm not 100% percent sure those regular expressions behave correctly in any entry situation. Anyway, thanks for your patience. When I run that code using the fields added with javascript (those in the last part of the set of validations) oddly enough it produces the last echo statement in the first set, as if the variables were not set, and finally, if I run the script against the first set of fields in the form, it produces an error in the mysql query and adds nothing to the database.

OK, I posted that large code and kept working on it, I got to handle the queries to the database correctly now (something I should have done earlier if I had paid more attention). Now the only problems are: one, I keep getting an error message of two variables not set if I submit the form with the added fields (I must add that the form not only has additional fields, it also removes other fields previously displayed). But the queries are working alright. I keep thinking the problem is that I want PHP to manage the same form with different fields, do the queries at the same time (within one block of code), but still take a decision as to build the queries depending on which $_POST variables are set. Besides, now I also have the problem of the errors I put into an array not being shown, I guess I'll keep wondering why this happens when I build two queries in the same block, while on the other forms, as I mentioned, I can perfectly validate their entry and show the errors alright.

The code I have ended up with is:

```
else    if(isset($_POST['EgresoLic'])&&isset($_POST['IngresoLic'])&&isset($_POST['genLic'])&&isset($_POST['facLic'])&&isset($_POST['titulo'])&&isset($_POST['CedProfLic'])&&isset($_POST['TesisLic']) &&isset($_POST['cuentaLic'])&&isset($_POST['BusquedaTerm'])){
require_once('libreria.php');
$EgresoLicenciado = $_POST['EgresoLic'];
if(!empty($EgresoLicenciado)) {
$EgresoLicencia = new Zend_Validate_Date;
if ($EgresoLicencia->isValid($EgresoLicenciado)) $EgresoLicen = $EgresoLicenciado; else     $errorsLic['fechaEgreso']="Escriba la fecha de egreso de licenciatura, formato AAAA-MM-DD (sólo números separados por guiones)";}
$IngresoLicenciado= $_POST['IngresoLic']; 
if(!empty($IngresoLicenciado)) {
$IngresoLicencia = new Zend_Validate_Date;
if ($IngresoLicencia->isValid($IngresoLicenciado)) $IngresoLicen = $IngresoLicenciado;   else $errorsLic['fechaIngreso']="Escriba la fecha de ingreso a licenciatura, formato AAAA-MM-DD (sólo números separados por guiones";}
$GenerLicenciado =$_POST['genLic'];
if(!empty($GenerLicenciado)) {
if($GenerLicenciado !="" && preg_match('/^\d{4}/', $GenerLicenciado)==true) $GenerLic=  $GenerLicenciado;
else  $errorsLic['generacion'] = "Escriba el año de su generación en formato AAAA";}
$cuentaDep= $_POST['cuentaLic']; //Escribir validación de cuenta ---------------->  pendiente
$FacultadLic= $_POST['facLic']; if(!empty($FacultadLic)){
if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){6,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==5)) $FacultLic =     $FacultadLic; 
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==4)) $FacultLic =    $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==3)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==2)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==1)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else if($FacultadLic !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){1,}/', $FacultadLic)==true && substr_count($FacultadLic, ' ')==0)) $FacultLic = $FacultadLic;
else $errorsLic['facultad']= "Escriba la facultad en que estudió la licenciatura";}
$Titulado = $_POST['titulo'];
$CedulaLic = $_POST['CedProfLic']; if(!empty($CedulaLic)) {if($CedulaLic !="" && preg_match('/\d{2,9}/', $CedulaLic)==true) $CedLic=$CedulaLic; else     $errorsLic['cedula']="Escriba el número de su cédula profesional";}
$TesisLicenciado = $_POST['TesisLic'];
if (!empty($TesisLicenciado)) { 
if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){11,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==10))     $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){10,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==9))   $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){9,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==8))     $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){8,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==7)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){7,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==6)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){6,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==5)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==4)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==3)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==2)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else if($TesisLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==1) || (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $TesisLicenciado)==true && substr_count($TesisLicenciado, ' ')==2)) $TesisLicen=$TesisLicenciado;
else $errorsLic['tesis']="Escriba el título de su tesis de licenciatura";}
include ('conect_gral.php');//importante incluir este archivo en todas las consultas, y sustituirlo por uno seguro con contraseña;
$registrobuscado=$_POST['BusquedaTerm'];
if (!isset($AsesorLic) || !isset($Modalidad)|| !isset($TitProyecto)) {
$cons4="SELECT CompletoApellidos FROM seguimientoegresados WHERE CompletoApellidos='registrobuscado'";
$regisLic = "UPDATE datos_licenciatura SET Fecha_Egreso_Lic='$EgresoLicen', Fecha_Ingreso_Lic='$IngresoLicen', Ced_Profesional_Lic='$CedLic', Facultad_Lic='$FacultLic', Generacion_Lic='$GenerLic', Cuenta_Dependencia='$cuentaDep', Tesis_Lic='$TesisLicen' WHERE Apellido_Licen='$registrobuscado'";
$regisGrad= "UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Licenciado' WHERE  Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
if($Titulado=='pasante') $regisGrad="UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Pasante' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
$consultacuatro=mysql_query($cons4);
$registroLic = mysql_query($regisLic);
$registroGrado = mysql_query($regisGrad);
if (!$registroLic || !$registroGrado) echo "Ocurrió un error al registrar los datos en la Base de Datos Registro Básico";   
if (!$consultacuatro) {echo "No se ha podido localizar al usuario";}
}
//captura de datos de pasantes-->
//PRIMERA PARTE DEL FORMULARIO REVISAR
//captura de datos de pasantes-->
if(isset($_POST['asesor_proy'])) {
$AsesorLicenciado = $_POST['asesor_proy'];
if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==4))     $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==3)) $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==2)) $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado;
else if($AsesorLicenciado  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $AsesorLicenciado)==true && substr_count($AsesorLicenciado, ' ')==1))    $AsesorLic=$AsesorLicenciado; 
else $errorsLic['asesor_pas']="Escriba el nombre del asesor de su proyecto de pasante";    }
if(isset($_POST['modalidad']))
$Modalidad =$_POST['modalidad'];
if(isset($_POST['proyecto'])) {
$TituloProyecto= $_POST['proyecto'];
if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){10,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==9)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){9,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==8)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){8,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==7)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){7,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==6)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){6,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==5)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){5,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==4)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){4,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==3)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){3,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==2)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){2,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==1)) $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else if($TituloProyecto  !="" && (preg_match('/^\D([[:alpha:]ñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]*\B[^0-9]+\D\b){1,}/', $TituloProyecto)==true && substr_count($TituloProyecto, ' ')==0))  $TitProyecto=$TituloProyecto;
else $errorsLic['proyecto']="Escriba el título de su proyecto de pasante"; }
include ('conect_gral.php');//importante incluir este archivo en todas las consultas, y sustituirlo por uno seguro con contraseña;
$registrobuscado=$_POST['BusquedaTerm'];
if (!empty($AsesorLic) && !empty($Modalidad) && !empty($TitProyecto)){
$cons11="SELECT CompletoApellidos FROM seguimientoegresados WHERE CompletoApellidos='registrobuscado'";
$regisPas="UPDATE datos_licenciatura SET Fecha_Egreso_Lic='$EgresoLicen', Fecha_Ingreso_Lic='$IngresoLicen', Facultad_Lic='$FacultLic', Generacion_Lic='$GenerLic', Cuenta_Dependencia='$cuentaDep', Asesor_Pas='$AsesorLic', Proyecto_Pas='$TitProyecto', Modalidad_Pas='$Modalidad' WHERE Apellido_Licen='$registrobuscado'"; 
$regisGrad= "UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Licenciado' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
if($Titulado=='pasante') $regisGrad="UPDATE estudios_grado SET Grado='Pasante' WHERE Apellidos_Grado='$registrobuscado'";
$consultaonce=mysql_query($cons11);
$registroPas = mysql_query($regisPas);
$registroGrado = mysql_query($regisGrad);
if (!$registroPas || !$registroGrado) echo "Ocurrió un error al registrar los datos en la Base de Datos Registro Pasante";  
if (!$consultaonce) {echo "No se ha podido localizar al usuario";}
}
}
```

I must say I do exactly the same verification of the fields on the other forms, with all that messing around with regular expresssions, and on those forms I do get the errors to pass to arrays of errors, while on this form, I guess because I am doing two queries, I can't build the array. Also, I think the part on the first query where I check to see if the variables of the second (optional) fields of the forms are submitted, is overriden by the way the two queries work together, I mean when I put:

```
if (!isset($AsesorLic) || !isset($Modalidad)|| !isset($TitProyecto))
```

it actually checks nothing because at that point obviously those variables aren't set, but I can't figure out what to do, I must check if the variables are set if I must mention them, and if I also check if they are empty I will also get a result of true, at that point. 
How can I actually check if there's no input to the optional fields?

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to do, to me it seems that you have three conditions you want to check: one if the "first set of fields is submitted", second if the "other fields from js are not submitted" and third if a database query should be performed. it would be really helpful if you would show all your code, especially how you nested your if-statements.

Comment: It looks like you're reassigning from $_POST to other variables - which depending on how you're assigning those variables, may make the isset() return true; can we see the variable assignment code?

Comment: @ndm yes its compromised and I'll change it. Thank you very much. I'll repost if you care to follow the question afterwards.

Comment: @ndm ha ha ha! (Laugh)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you should use two separate forms and have them named differently. That way you can simply check which form is submitted.

```
<form name="firstForm" method="post">
<!-- Input tags go here -->
<input type="submit" name="first-submit" value="First Form Submitted" />
</form>

<form name="secondForm" method="post">
<!-- Input tags go here -->
<input type="submit" name="second-submit" value="Second Form Submitted" />
</form>
```

For your HTML example.  Then this for PHP:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['first-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}

if (!empty($_POST['second-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}
?>
```

That way you know which set of fields they were trying to submit.  Then you can do your checks to see if they are empty and make sure that you strip any bad characters to prevent hacking. Or preferably do some prepared statements.

Comment: Yes I did thought of making two forms and then showing/hiding them with javascript, but unless I could use two forms and then set only a submit for one of them, maybe passing the values of the first one to the second with javascript, I wouldn't like to (apart from the previous technique being far too convoluted and depending on javascript being  active). Although maybe I will end up doing that. I will post the entire code, however large it is, hoping you folks can help me out. @matthias Yes I am trying to check for those 3 conditions, but it is the logic that beats me.

Comment: Yeah please do.  I am having a hard time figuring out what the issue is.  It seems to me if you want to process it all as one form then you are doing it the right way, although I probably wouldn't do it all in one big statement like that I would do each one individually, set a local variable then test if it was empty before putting it in the query.  If they are in the same form, all of the values will come back, null or otherwise.

Comment: I find it interesting to process each variable individually, but what I can do right now is my best shot. If you see the code I posted you can see I do my best to process each field doing a large amount of checks on each, but I must put everything inside a block because there are other forms being processed in the same script. Maybe you can suggest an alternate syntax?

Comment: Yeah especially for debugging purposes I would use some sort of boolean flag.  Then check all of the variables individually and set the flag and then run your code on it.  It is very hard to tell debugging when you combine it all in one condition like that which one is not set right.

Comment: Solved it! Well, almost. I just had to change the first query of place, after all of the variables are defined. Like I said there was no use doing `if (!isset($AsesorLic) || !isset($Modalidad)|| !isset($TitProyecto))` at the point where those werent defined. Then I just had to check for the other post variables and lastly do that first query (the one for the default fields in the form). I only have one question though. Currently every error is checked and notified, except for those in the optional fields because I have to enclose the code for those in blocks. ¿How can it be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry PHP is not getting confused if variables are names similarly :)

What's probably happening is that under certain circumstances both if statements return true causing the logic to go haywire.

Feel free to update the whole page and we'll try our best to help you.

Hope this was helpful,

Pesach